Is one Chayav for burning the Korbanos of Erev Shabbos on Shabbos?
The Gemara (Shabbos 24b) states that the Korbanos that were brought on Erev Shabbos may not be burned on Shabbos, based on the דיוק of ״עולת שבת בשבתו״ - that only the Korbanos that were brought on Shabbos may be burned on Shabbos.
My question is: if someone burned the Korbanos of Erev Shabbos on Shabbos, is he Chayav as if he did a regular Melachah, or is it only a ביטול עשה?

See Pesachim 72
